# cannot resolved method 'putExtra(java.lang.String, java.util.List<java.lang.String>)

Tags: java, android

```
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {/da
            @Override//s
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent postDetailActivity = new Intent(mContext, PostDetailActivity.class); //s
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                postDetailActivity.putExtra("fname",mData.get(position).getPRFCOACHFNAME());
                postDetailActivity.putExtra("lname",mData.get(position).getPRFCOACHLNAME());
                postDetailActivity.putExtra("expertise",mData.get(position).getPRFCOACHSPECIALIZATION()); // this is where the problem
                postDetailActivity.putExtra("skill",mData.get(position).getPRFCOACHSKILL());
                postDetailActivity.putExtra("technique",mData.get(position).getPRFCOACHTECHNIQUE());
                postDetailActivity.putExtra("control",mData.get(position).getPRFCOACHCONTROL());
                postDetailActivity.putExtra("management",mData.get(position).getPRFCOACHMANAGEMENT());
                mContext.startActivity(postDetailActivity);
            }
        });//sa
```

//sadsada
The getPRFCOACHSPECIALIZATION error, cannot resolved

Comment: Welcome! Could you possibly add more context, like what program this is and what libraries you use, and what you're even trying  to do?

Answer (score 2):

To pass a `List<String>`, you need to use `putStringArrayListExtra`.

Instead of using

```
postDetailActivity.putExtra("expertise",mData.get(position).getPRFCOACHSPECIALIZATION());
```

Use

```
postDetailActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("expertise",mData.get(position).getPRFCOACHSPECIALIZATION());
```